# Page rendered is empty even though view and controller exist.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I'm following [this article](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic)(http://asciicasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic), I'm not using nifty generator tho.

I've done the User model and `localhost:3000/users/new` page works fine.

But when I try to open `localhost:3000/login`, the page is just empty. The source is empty too.

I've just copied the source from the site.

routes.rb

```
map.login 'login', :controller => 'user_sessions', :action => 'new'
map.logout 'logout', :controller => 'user_sessions', :action => 'destroy'
map.resources :user_sessions
map.resources :users
```

user_sessions_controller.rb

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully logged in."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user_session = UserSession.find
    @user_session.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully logged out."
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

/views/user_sessions/new.html.erb

```
<% form_for @user_session do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

The code is just same as the site.

The server console shows that the views are being rendered:

> Completed 200 OK in 149ms (Views: 145.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)

Why is the login form not displayed at all?

**Update**

After added new action 'index' into user_sessions controller(also plus index.html.erb), if I open `localhost:3000/user_sessions/index` shows me below message.

> Unknown action
>   No action responded to show. Actions: create, destroy, index, and new

And, this is WEBrick output

> Processing UserSessionsController#show
>   (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-01-22 12:47:10)
>   [GET]
>
> Parameters: {"id"=>"index"}
>
> ActionController::UnknownAction (No
>   action responded to show. Actions:
>   create, destroy, index, and new):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the reason.

There was nothing in Views/layouts/application.html.erb, the file is exist, tho.

Answer (score 1):

`/views/new.html.erb` should be located at `views/user_sessions/new.html.erb`

Comment: Sorry, it is where you noted. miss typing. I've modified the path in my question.